# "An error has occured"

Tags: apt, package-management, wine

Firstly I don't know anything about this 'error' its always there and when it isn't is never.

[image]

That's the icon but here is what it says when I click on it or hover over:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click
>   menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message
>   was: 'Unknown error '' ("The cache has no package
>   named 'wine-devel-i386'"). This usually means that your installed
>   packages have unmet independences

That is it, I ran `apt-get` in terminal but nothing happened only showed me what apt-get does and the package manager is not in the right click menu.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I only use Wine for one program which is [Cinebench](http://www.maxon.net/products/cinebench/overview.html) to stress my CPU

Thanks for reading! And any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge wine'

Comment: If you are still here I can help you it you want to chat with me?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`. [Edit] the outputs into your question (please don't comment them).

Comment: @MathCubes sorry about that i was away for 5 mins

Comment: @Isaac try wants Zamhareel said.  I forgot about that command since I now use Arch.

Comment: @MathCubes okay sure

Comment: @Zacharee1 i have done it but it didnt install any just said 7 not to upgrade and everything else stayed the way it was

Comment: @Isaac Press 'y' on your keyboard than, 'enter'

Comment: @Isaac Then see what `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` does.

Comment: @MathCubes http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36864/stuff

Comment: @Isaac http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36864/stuff

Comment: @Zacharee1 '0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.'

Comment: @Isaac Did the first operation do anything? Because there's a difference of 7 there compared to before.

Comment: @Zacharee1 they both didnt do nothing even though they had a difference of 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error points to wine and the i386 architecture.

PART A - If you are using a 64bit machine enable 32bit architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Reboot. Test. If that works great, thats all it was! If that doesn't work I'd go to part B

PART B - I'd roll my sleeves up and start really troubleshooting by updating and upgrading.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then restarting:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

If that error still doesn't go away after updating and upgrading and rebooting what I'd do at this point is go to part C

PART -C: Completely remove wine.

```
sudo service wine stop
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get purge wine
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
```

That removes it and its dependencies and resources. Then restart.

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

If no error after restart then the error was directly related to wine; which if you do not need it then continue on without it. If there error is still there at this point then I'm stumped and would start looking at the hardware I'm using and I'd double check I have the most up to date versions on EVERYTHING installed.

If you do need wine, now or at a later point, then I'd go with wineHQ:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Good luck with your trusty tahr!!